# Error: Opening recordset with SQL statement MsAccess

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, vba

my goal is to test a table for a record and if that specific record exists, do nothing, else do some insert record.  I wrote the following SQL statement to try and retrieve the specific record

```
Update: Dim strSQL2 As String
        Dim objRecordset As ADODB.Recordset
Dim BatchID As Long
Dim instrumentName As String
strSQL2 = "SELECT * FROM tblInstrumentInterfacelog " & _
          "WHERE BatchID = " & BatchID & " " & _
          "AND InstrumentName = '" & InstrumentName & "'" 
Set objRecordset = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL2, dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
If objRecordset.RecordCount > 0 Then
Else
"logic to insert record"
End if
```

I get an error *type Mismatch* at the line

```
Set objRecordset = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL2, dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
```

The schema for tblInstrumentInterfaceLog is:

- [InstrumentInterfaceLogID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
- [InstrumentName] nvarchar NOT NULL
- [BatchID] [int] NOT NULL
- [FileName] nvarchar NOT NULL

I only need help on the provided code, why is this type mismatch occurring?

Comment: Where do you declare the objRecordset variable?

Comment: added the more declarations

Comment: Refer opening recordset section http://www.classanytime.com/mis333k/sjdaoadorecordsets.html

Comment: Where do you open the connection to SQL?  Also, you should list out the fields instead of using `SELECT *` and you should test for an empty recordset by using `IF objRecordset.EOF`.

Answer (score 0):

I have always had success with just using `Set objRecordset = CurrentDB.OpenRecordset(strSQL2)`

Could you post the specific error message?

Could you try using a DAO.recordset?

Answer (score 0):

From what you have posted, the two variables in your sql statment are not actually set to anything. Try printing out strSQL2 in a msgbox and make sure it is valid SQL.

Also try replacing `Dim objRecordset As ADODB.Recordset` with `Dim objRecordset As Recordset`.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
Dim objRecordset As ADODB.Recordset
```

With

```
Dim objRecordset As DAO.Recordset
```

as evan said.